# Cast from [SKNode]? to unrelated type 'String' always fails - SpriteKit, UIKit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit

I have a project where I need to combine SpriteKit with UIKit. For most of the project is use UIKit but now I need to make a very small game within my project where i will have to use SpriteKit. I created a UIViewController and imported SpriteKit. I then created a GameScene and the game works properly etc.

My problem is that SpriteKit ruined every object in my other ViewControllers where a bracket is used. I get the following error message:

**"Cast from [SKNode]? to unrelated type 'String' (or 'Int') always fails".**

Example:

TimerFunction: if let rowToReload = timer.userInfo?["row"] as? Int

```
func cellShouldUpdateTimer(timer: NSTimer!) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        if let rowToReload = timer.userInfo?["row"] as? Int {

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowToReload, inSection: 0)

            if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CompCell {
                self.configureCompCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }
   }
```

or in my json: jsonData["messages"]?[0]["unread_messages"] as? String

```
    do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary

    let unreadMessages = jsonData["messages"]?[0]["unread_messages"] as? String
```

Comment: Where do you fill up your timer.userInfo?

Comment: I'm passing a string with a date from a tableviewcell that updates every second. Any ideas on the unreadMessages?

Comment: "string with a date", so the string is under the "row" key, right? About unreadMessages, since NSJSONSerialization can't create SKNode from a jsonString, this row: jsonData["messages"]?[0]["unread_messages"] will never be '[SKNode]?', it can be only '[AnyObject]?'.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. 

let MessageDict = jsonData["messages"] as? [AnyObject]
let MessageArr = MessageDict![0] as? NSDictionary
let unreadMessages = MessageArr!["unread_messages"] as? String